# trying to create a refreshing button for gridview

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, gridview, datagridview

I have made an c# program to access a database and write some data to it, and show it in a grid-view.
That all works but now i want the grid-view to refresh because it wont show the data i just entered into the database

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;


namespace ForexDev
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private OleDbConnection Database1;
        private OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand();
        private string connParam = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\floortje\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ForexDev\ForexDev\Database11.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";

        public Form1()
        {
            Database1 = new OleDbConnection(connParam);
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                Database1.Open();
                oledbcmd.Connection = Database1;
                oledbcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Forex ([Order],[Tijd gekocht],Type,Groote,Symbool,[Koers inkoop],[S/l],[T/p],[Koers Verkoop],[Profit/Loss]) VALUES ('" + this.txtOrder.Text + "','" + this.txtTijd.Text + "','" + this.txtType.Text + "','" + this.txtgroote.Text + "','" + this.txtSymb.Text + "','" + this.txtKoop.Text + "','" + this.StopLoss.Text + "','" + this.TakeProfit.Text + "','" + this.txtVerkoop.Text + "','" + this.Winstverl.Text + "');";
                oledbcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                int temp = oledbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
                dataGridView1.Update();
                Database1.Close();


                if (temp > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Added");

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed");
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database11DataSet.Forex' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.forexTableAdapter.Fill(this.database11DataSet.Forex);



        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Database1.Close();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Database1.Open();

            this.dataGridView1.Refresh();
            this.dataGridView1.Update();
            Database1.Close();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: then what is the error you are facing ?

Comment: there is no error but it doesn't refresh.
So i have  a grid view i can write data to it,but the newly entered data doesn't show up.

Comment: where do you databind your grid ?

Comment: I don't ? i inserted the data grid using visual studio by means of dragging it there and then a dialog opens in wich i can connect it to the database.

Comment: can you see data in grid view without binding grid ?

Comment: I can see the data yes,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to thank you tariq for putting me on the right track, i did not mark your answer as the answer to my problem because of the following :

The answer to my problem was that i needed to bind the database to the gridview like this :
(and correct me if this is not databinding)

```
{

                    Database1.Open();
                    oledbcmd.Connection = Database1;
                    oledbcmd.CommandText = textBox1.Text;
                    oledbcmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Forex ([Order],[Tijd gekocht],Type,Groote,Symbool,[Koers inkoop],[S/l],[T/p],[Koers Verkoop],[Profit/Loss]) VALUES ('" + this.txtOrder.Text + "','" + this.txtTijd.Text + "','" + this.txtType.Text + "','" + this.txtgroote.Text + "','" + this.txtSymb.Text + "','" + this.txtKoop.Text + "','" + this.StopLoss.Text + "','" + this.TakeProfit.Text + "','" + this.txtVerkoop.Text + "','" + this.Winstverl.Text + "');";
                    oledbcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    int temp = oledbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\floortje\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ForexDev\ForexDev\Database11.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";
                    dataGridView1.Refresh();
                    this.dataGridView1.Refresh();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                    OleDbDataAdapter dd = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                    dd = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From Forex", Database1);
                    dd.Fill(dt);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;

                    Database1.Close();
```

Comment: You are welcome and now you are using datasource from code behind. This is better and solves this problem automatically. And you should accept your own answer, it will help others :)

Comment: Hi yeah i had to wait 2 days before i could do that or something so i just did thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Add this after making updates

```
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: When i do that i get
1 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)